# JavaFX: Pasar datos entre ventanas

Tags: java, javafx, parametros, ventana

Tengo una ventana "padre" con un ListView y un botón. La idea es que al hacer clic en el botón se abra una nueva ventana "hija" (la ventana "padre" se mantiene en segundo plano) con un boton "aceptar".

En la ventana "hija" relleno un ArrayList y al hacer clic en "aceptar" cierro la ventana "hija" y envío el ArrayList a la ventana "padre".

Esto lo tengo que repetir muchas veces, hasta conseguir poblar varias colecciones en la ventana "padre" usando varias ventanas "hija", por lo que no puedo permitirme crear una nueva ventana "padre" cada vez.

Este es el código que uso para abrir la ventana "hija":

```
private void anadirMateriales(){
    abrirVentana("AnadirMateriales.fxml", "Añadir materiales");
}

public ArrayList<String> materiales = new ArrayList<>();
private void abrirVentana(String fxml, String titulo){
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxml));

        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle(titulo);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.showAndWait();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Y en la ventana "hija" lo único que tengo es el código necesario para rellenar un ArrayList llamado "materiales".

Gracias ya de antemano por la ayuda, no sé qué haría sin esta comunidad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi recomendación es que implementes un método en el controlador de la ventana hija el cual reciba como parámetro un objeto de tipo lista (ej. `List`). Usando este método puedes pasar la instancia de la lista que deseas llenar en la ventana hija (en tu caso `materiales`) y cuando esta se cierre la lista contendrá los datos que necesitas.

```
public class ControladorVistaHija {

    private List<String> materiales;

    public void setListaMateriales(List<String> materiales) {
        this.materiales = materiales;
    }

    // Resto del código del controlador
}
```

Luego, antes de mostrar la vista hija, debes obtener la referencia al controlador e invocar, en este, el método creado pasándole la instancia de la lista (`materiales`).

```
public ArrayList<String> materiales = new ArrayList<>();
private void abrirVentana(String fxml, String titulo){
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxml));

        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle(titulo);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        // Pasamos la lista al controlador usando el método implementado
        ControladorVistaHija controlador = (ControladorVistaHija) fxmlLoader.getController();
        controlador.setListaMateriales(materiales);

        stage.showAndWait();

        // Cuando la ejecución del programa llegue aquí la lista materiales
        // contendrá los datos que se le hayan insertado
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de haber marcado la respuesta de E.Betanzos como respuesta porque me sirvió para el problema que estaba tratando de resolver, la cual además agradezco muchísimo, me he encontrado un caso parecido en el que por alguna razón que aún desconozco no conseguía devolver a la ventana "padre" los datos que esta me había enviado y que luego había manipulado en la ventana "hija".

La solución ha sido la siguiente:

```
//Pongamos que en la ventana "padre" tengo una lista llamada "listaDeLaVentanaPadre"
//que quiero modificar desde la ventana "hija" y obtener el resultado de nuevo en la
//ventana "padre"

//En la ventana "hija" tengo un método al cual llamo desde la ventana "padre" antes de
//cargarla
public void parametros(ArrayList<String>() lista, ControladorVentanaPadre cvp){
    miCvp = cvp;
    miLista = lista
}

//También en la ventana "hija", después de manipular la lista, quiero devolvérsela a
//la ventana "padre".
//Para lograrlo, en el método asignado en este caso al botón "Aceptar" ...
public void aceptar(){
    miCvp.listaDeLaVentanaPadre = miLista;
    //La siguiente línea cierra la ventana
    botonAceptar.getScene().getWindow().close();
}


//Aunque no sé si es necesario decirlo, en la ventana "padre", cargo la ventana "hija"
//de la siguiente manera.
try {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("VentanaHija.fxml"));
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    
    ControladorVentanaHija controlador = (ControladorVentanaHija) fxmlLoader.getController();

    controlador.parametros(listaDeLaVentanaPadre, this);
     
    stage.showAndWait();

    //Como decía E.Betanzos, el programa llegará a este punto una vez la ventana
    //"hija" se cierre.            
    //PoblarFormulario se encarga de coger los valores de la lista manipulada y
    //rellenar el listView correspondiente
    poblarFormulario();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("IO Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Espero que esto le llegue a servir a alguien con el mismo problema que yo en un futuro

Un saludo!